# How to set a form as pristine?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

- The form that represents entity state is being edited (turns dirty)
- The form is being submitted and entity state is now aligned with the form state which means that the form should now be set as pristine.

How do we do that? 
There was `$setPristine()` in ng1.
Btw, I'm talking about `ControlGroup` type of form.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is the `markAsPristine` method (it seems undocumented for now, but can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/53f0c2206df6a5f8ee03d611a7563ca1a78cc82d/tools/public_api_guard/forms/index.d.ts#L42).

Basically, `this.form.markAsPristine()` does what you expect.

Answer (score 15):

**update**

In the new forms module this was improved a lot.

[`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html), the base class of most form classes provides

```ts
markAsTouched({onlySelf}?: {onlySelf?: boolean}) : void
markAsUntouched({onlySelf}?: {onlySelf?: boolean}) : void
markAsDirty({onlySelf}?: {onlySelf?: boolean}) : void
markAsPristine({onlySelf}?: {onlySelf?: boolean}) : void
markAsPending({onlySelf}?: {onlySelf?: boolean}) : void
```

And several other new methods

```ts
disable({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean}) : void
enable({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean}) : void
```

```ts
setValue(value: any, options?: Object) : void
patchValue(value: any, options?: Object) : void
```

```ts
reset(value?: any, options?: Object) : void
updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean,  emitEvent?: boolean}) : void // (old)
setErrors(errors: {[key: string]: any}, {emitEvent}?: {emitEvent?: boolean}) : void
```

**original**

That's currently not supported. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5568 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933. The usual workaround is to re-create the form to get a pristine one.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyComp {
   form = new FormGroup({
      first: new FormControl('Nancy'),
      last: new FormControl('Drew')
   });
}

   reset() {
      this.form.reset();  // will reset to null
     // this.form.reset({first: 'Nancy', last: 'Drew'});   -- will reset to value specified
   }
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9974

This will show up in rc5 or later.